# Check if user has leveled up

Tags: python

I need to check if the user has leveled up. I have a `level_to_xp`, `xp_to_level`, and a `get_next_level` function. I just can't get `has_leveled_up` to work.

```py
def level_to_xp(level):
    return 25 * level * (1+level)

def xp_to_level(xp):
    return math.sqrt(4 * xp + 25) / 10 - 0.5

def get_next_level(xp):
    return level_to_xp(round(xp_to_level(xp) + 0.501))
```

I have tried doing this

```py
def has_leveled_up(xp):
    return round(xp_to_level(xp)) == round(xp_to_level(get_next_level_xp(xp))) - 1 if round(xp_to_level(xp)) != 0 else False
```

which returns false till level 1 was hit, but it stays true for a little bit longer after that.

I need it to return true only if the current level is equal to the past next level like

```
...
49 xp: False
50 xp: True
51: False
...
149: False
150: True
151: False
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but consider changing your design as follows. Add `add_xp(user, xp)` method and `get_xp_for_next_level(current_xp)` method. Finally it would be `add_xp(user, xp)` method's responsibility to emit `level_up` event when needed. It seems wrong to have `has_leveled_up` depending on `xp` only. Don't you want the event to fire only once per level?

Comment: @freakish Hmm I'll try that and see which one I like better. Thanks

Comment: Or you could initialize xp to the amount required to level up and then _subtract_ from it as they gain experience.  When it goes negative, they've leveled up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:-

```
def has_leveled_up(xp):
   return xp_to_level(xp) == math.ceil(xp_to_level(xp - 1))
```